# Bootsrap carousel image size's are changing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, carousel

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/login-screen-with-form

the above link carousel is changing size for each images.I even tried to change the width and height of the carousel-inner and carousel and img but this did not work.

I have tried resizing the image size to `max-height:100%` and also `width:100%`  but this also did not work.

Comment: set max-height for the banner-sec and it will work

Comment: add a code snippet and someone from the community would help resolve this for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
.carousel-item{
   height:500px;
}
.carousel-item img{
   object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: how to make the image to stretch to full height and width

Comment: add css on img  >   object-fit: cover;